# Rails setups postgresql database without primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

I messed around a bit with my database and because I screwed things up I figured to start from scratch and setup the postgresql database again.

```
rake db:setup
rake db:migrate
```

However, now I got all kinds of errors in my app. When comparing the pg_dump of this broken database with the working one I still have on heroku, I can see that the biggest differences are that some of the `id` columns don't get defined as a primary key on my local database (so the `NOT NULL` part is missing when defining the `id` column on my local database).
And there are also no `SEQUENCES` made for these `id's` on my local database

Comparing schema.rb on my local machine and heroku I see that the difference is that on my local machine a column `id` is defined for these tables and on heroku not. 
So for example on my local machine I get

```
  create_table "pictures", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|

    t.integer  "id",                 limit: 8
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "image"
    t.text     "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size",    limit: 8
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "post_id",            limit: 8
  end
```

and on heroku that first line `t.integer id     limit:8` is missing.

Now my 2 questions are,

- would this difference cause those differences in my databases?
- if so, why does heroku have a different schema.rb when both applications have the same migrations?

Comment: you don't need to add `id` column to your table,rails does it for you,also it set `primary_key` to `id` 
 Docs http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table

Comment: `db:setup` loads the schema into the database, which I guess would then mean migrate does nothing.  I think the changes in the schema are because you'd messed around with your db then done something which caused the schema to be dumped from the db to `db/schema.rb`. To restart completely you'd need to drop the db then recreate it and migrate

Comment: j-dexx, so if I understand you correctly, my postgresql database actually can alter my applications `db/schema.rb'?

Comment: Actually, thinking about this, it makes sense that this happend! If you write out an answer, I'll accept it